# Purchasing train tickets at Helsinki airport

Tags: tickets, airport-transfer, hel

Arriving Helsinki & going to Central Station.  When purchasing tickets at the airport, will the machines take credit cards?   What is the approximate cost of a ticket?
Thanks BR

Comment: @NicolasB From the airport to the central railway station, as the question says.

Answer (score 2):

For a journey between the airport and Helsinki central, you will require a 'Regional' type ticket (see [the HSL website](https://www.hsl.fi/en/information/how-use-public-transport/visitors) for further information on what different ticket types cover)

At the current date, the single price for this journey is €5 if bought from a ticket machine (the website linked above states that these do accept cards *with a chip*) or €4.20 if you download the HSL app and buy the ticket there (I used the app as a tourist on my last visit to Helsinki). The ticket will be valid for 90 minutes from the time of purchase.

Comment: Addition: The HSL app accepts credit cards for payments.